# How to create tile button with text style as shown below? IN Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am trying to create a flip button that shows changing content on every alternate flip. UI looks something like this:

[image]

On every alternate flip the text will change in place of sample text 1, 2,3 and 4

I am trying to use Hub tile provided in windows phone control toolkit but facing issue that how can i show the text in the given format and change it on flip.

Text i will be getting from web service.

How can i achieve this or is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start screen tiles, you can only have a single front and a single back to a tile between executions of your app.

The only exception is that they can change on runs of a background agent, but this only occurs around every half hour (depending on how often your phone decides to run them) and there is a hard limit on the number of apps that can have background agents enabled at a time.

For in-app tiles, your best bet is to update the tile based on a timer.

You will need to programmatically build up an image, save it to Isolated Storage and assign it to the `BackBackgroundImage` to do any special formatting on the tile back.

Comment: How can i create an image with the text shown in second tile and then display all those images one after the other on flip of a tile?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is basically check the amount of times it has been tapped/clicked and then adjust the text accordingly. For example, upon every tick, you increment a value by 1. You then qualify that number with the index of an array of images and make the background of that image equal to whichever image is being pointed to in the array.

Hope that makes sense.